# Keyboard shortcut not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am using HandsOnTable jquery plugin, and I'm trying to handle a specific key combination (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>)  shortcut. But it is not working for some reason, here is my code and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDQ3z/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var isCtrl = false;
var isShift = false;
var isAlt = false;
// action on key up
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 17) {
        isCtrl = false;
    }
    if (e.which == 16) {
        isShift = false;
    }
    if (e.which == 18) {
        isAlt = false;
    }
});
// action on key down
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 17) {
        isCtrl = true;
    }
    if (e.which == 16) {
        isShift = true;
    }
    if (e.which == 18) {
        isAlt = true;
    }
    if (e.which == 86 && isAlt) //alt+v
    {
        console.log("alt+v detected");
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using chromium and it looks like all the keydown events do not fire. I found out there is a [beforeKeyDown](http://handsontable.com/demo/beforeKeyDown.html) callback, which can be used to "modify keybindings". Using that seems to work:

```
$('#example').handsontable({
    data: data,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    beforeKeyDown: function (e) {
        if (e.altKey === true && e.which === 86) {
            console.log("alt-v");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JdzR3/

Comment: Thank you. But it seems to delete the content somehow. ANy idea why?

Comment: I don't know really. Please add an issue note on [GitHub](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues) and ask the developers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use the `altkey` property on the event.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

  if(e.altKey === true && key === 86){
     console.log("Alt+v");
  } 

});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.altKey for more about that and other key events.